# How do I delete a record in a table which has a primary key referenced in another table as foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In my database, I have a table say "employee" which has a primary key attribute "employee_id" and another attribute "salary".
There is another table say "employee_qualification" which has a foreign key attribute "employee_id".
So, how can I delete all the records from "employee" and "employee_qualifications" with salary=10000?

This doesn't seem to work.

`DELETE FROM employee WHERE employee.salary=10000;`

Comment: Configure the schema with [ON DELETE CASCADE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) (eg.) *or* manually remove the dependent records first. (I prefer latter, even though it may appear to be more work: it's also more controlled and explicit.)

Comment: i came across `ON DELETE CASCADE` on google somewhere, but where exactly is this to be written?

Comment: See the link above - it's used to configure the Foreign Key definition of the dependent table.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute two statements.

```
DELETE FROM employee_qualifications WHERE employee_qualifications.employee_id in (SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE employee.salary=10000)
DELETE FROM employee WHERE employee.salary=10000
```

While this will work, it could leave some orphaned records in the employee_qualifications table. The below option will clean the orphaned records.

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE employee.salary=10000
DELETE FROM employee_qualifications WHERE employee_qualifications.employee_id Not in (SELECT employee_id FROM employee)
```

Comment: [MySQL requires that the DRI constraint hold immediately and *does not supported deferred constraint checking*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html). Thus there can never be orphaned records in MySQL when DRI is used. To prevent "orphans" (to ensure the delete doesn't fail when deleting rows from the primary table), use the appropriate transactions. Even in a DB that *did* support deferred checks, the operation could still fail (on the commit) if not appropriately guarded.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL allows deletes from multiple tables at the same time.  So you can do:

```
DELETE e, eq
    FROM employee e JOIN
         employee_qualitifications eq
    WHERE e.employee_id = eq.employee_id AND
          e.salary = 10000;
```

Comment: That's pretty slick. Does it also imply one [implicit] transaction?

Comment: @user2864740 . . . That might depend on the storage engine being used.  InnoDB does the delete in a single transaction, and I would expect that to be true of multi-table deletes as well.